# How can I best type a python function returning a named tuple type

Tags: python, mypy

In python 3.11 (mypy 1.7.0) I have a function that constructs a dynamic NamedTuple type. It returns the type constructed - not an instance.
I first tried typing it with `Type[NamedTuple]`, but that causes python to expect the named tuple constructor itself, not a subclass.

I tried a protocol such as:

```py
class PNamedTuple(Protocol):
    _fields: Sequence[str]
```

And used `Type[PNamedTuple]` as my function. This allows me to create a namedtuple class dynamically. However, when I access `_fields` I get an error:

`"_fields" is protected and used outside of the class in which it is declared`

1. Can I do anything to suppress this error? It doesn't occur for `NamedTuple` subtypes - how can I replicate this behavior?
2. Is there a simple way to inherit from another protocol to express the "tuple-like" behavior? `PNamedTuple(Sequence, Protocol)` doesn't work as Sequence is not a Protocol. Is there a simple work around for this?

**UPDATE**

1. NamedTuple isn't a class, so `Type[NamedTuple]` is misguided. (See accepted answer by @blhsing.)
2. As @dROOOze points out, the `_fields` error is coming from pylance (and thus from pyright, I think). The solution seemed to give me an error for the same reason (pyright), but mypy is fine with it, and the protocol class is not needed.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean you're using [mypy *1.7.0*](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/#history) - there was never a 0.7.

Comment: @l0b0! Right - typo; thanks!

Comment: `"_fields" is protected and used outside of the class in which it is declared` does not look like a mypy message - that's from your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply type hinting that the function returns a `NamedTuple` type would work:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Iterable, Any

def foo(name: str, fields: Iterable[tuple[str, Any]]) -> NamedTuple:
    return NamedTuple(name, fields)

print(foo('foo', [('a', int), ('b', str)])._fields)
```

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=d14c925cb50ea47e8bda33e45eeb6afd

Comment: I am actually returning a subtype of NamedTuple - not an instance. On inside of function I have `sub = namedtuple(...); return sub`. The caller uses this type to construct named tuples.

Comment: That's exactly what the `foo` function above does. It returns a `namedtuple` type `foo`, not an instance of it. Demo: https://ideone.com/TJr1uZ

Comment: It is typed to return an instance, not a type

Comment: No. `NamedTuple` is a class factory that returns a type, so by typing a function to return a `NamedTuple` it precisely means to return a type. See the demo above, where the returning value of the function is assigned to `t` and `t` is then called to produce an actual instance, so it is clear that `t` is a type.

Comment: Aha -- you are exactly right. I get an error here, but just as the problem with `_fields`, as @dROOOze points out, it is a pyright error via pylance in vscode, not mypy. Ok - thanks.